# Matching Users Based On Info They Have Submitted

Tags: java, netbeans, match, criteria

Now I know this is a very broad question, and that is why I expect a broad answer. I'm just looking to be steered in the right direction.
Simply put, I am intending to make a website where users can include specific data in their profile and be matched with other users that have entered corresponding data in order to create a "match".
Similar to a dating site that matches users based on best "chemistry". However, this is even simpler than that. I do have coding experience in NetBeans and am constantly expanding my knowledge of website development.

For example:

```
101, 102 and 103 = MATCH  
User A - Data [User lists they have 101]
User B - Data [User lists they have 102 and 103]
```

Either User A or B uses "Find Users Who Complete Your Set" and a table or column lists said users who complete this set.

So, if anyone can at least point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated! I have made several website on Webs.com but I don't believe their tools come with anything similar to filling this need. I intend to program this matching system using Java (likely with NetBeans) and implementing into the website. Thanks guys!!!

Comment: Are you going to use a database?

Comment: I assume that would be the best route. I've never built a website from scratch I'll be researching this goal for a while. I just need a good foundation to get me going.

Comment: Are you familiar with `JDBC`? Can you write SQL Queries?

Comment: I'm familiar with Google haha. I love to research and learn about this stuff because I'm going to school for Computer IT so if you recommend I become more familiar with those then I will.

Comment: I took Programming with Java for one semester so I know how to create simple applications and have a good basic understanding. But I've never implemented data online or between two users. Just one user responding to questions, options, etc. I really will be starting with almost no knowledge of the deep technical workings of this goal.

Comment: Good luck with that. If after just "Intro to Java" you can create a functional dynamic site - you have a really bright future ahead of you.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, just looking for the right direction. I have about a year to complete this so I'll continue researching and asking questions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use a database to store your users and also all possible sets of attributes that can be completed to make a match. Here's one way of creating such a database with PostgreSQL:

```
create table person (
  id int primary key,
  first_name text not null,
  attributes text[]
);

create table match (
  id int primary key,
  attributes text[] 
);

insert into person values (1, 'Bob', array['A']);
insert into person values (2, 'Alice', array['B','D']);
insert into person values (3, 'Carol', array['B','C']);
insert into person values (4, 'Ted', array['D']);
insert into match values (1, array['A','B','D']);
```

I'm using arrays instead junction tables to be less verbose. You can now find all persons that complete set #1 for Alice for example by running the following query:

```
select
  id,
  first_name
from  
  (select
    p2.id as id,
    p2.first_name as first_name,
    array(      
      select unnest(p1.attributes) union select unnest(p2.attributes)
    ) as match_potential
  from
    person p1
    inner join person p2 on (p1.id = 2 and p2.id <> 2)) as p
where
  p.match_potential @> (select attributes from match where id = 1);
```

Bob and Alice are now a match.

You would need to do something more sophisticated in the end but something like this should get you started on your website and would allow you to build your first prototype you can use to test your concept.